# Simple way to count characters using .keyup in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

```
<input type="text" />
```

How can I write the number of characters from `input` on `.keyup` in JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value.length);
});
```

`keyup` is a shortcut method for `bind('keyup')`.
And as of jQuery version 1.7, all of the above are deprecated we are encourage to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind events, meaning that the code should look like this:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    console.log(this.value.length);
});
```

Comment: *Too much jQuery.* `this.value.length` is also sufficient (instead of `$(this).val().length`).

Comment: Many thnx   Answers should also have been able to be bookmarked : )

Answer (score 6):

Example - This will alert out the number of characters

```
$('#textBoxId').bind('keyup', function(e){

     alert($(this).val().length);

});
```

This obviously assumes that the text box has an id of textBoxId. Otherwise change selector iof don't want to give it an id for some reason

Comment: That would only work if the input had an id of textbox.  `<input type="text" id="textbox" />`